# I keep getting 'unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference'

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, undefined-reference, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm testing independent pieces of a larger piece of code for functionality in MS CRM and I want to know why I keep getting the above error for this small piece of code:

```
function testThis()
{
    var optionset = document.getElementById("new_makeyear");
    console.log("this is supposed to be something " + optionset.Options.length);
}
```

"new_makeyear" is an option set. The log statement was just so I can see the behavior through the console. What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `optionset` is a DOM element; are you *sure* it has an `Options` attribute?

Comment: Accessing the DOM on Dynamics CRM web forms is not supported. When you need to access a specific field, take a look at the `Xrm.Page.getAttribute()` and `Xrm.Page.getControl()` functions. The DOM elements belonging to these fields have names suffixed with an underscore + character.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using DOM approach rather than using Xrm object model approach?

Answer (score 2):

As Henk mentioned in his comment, you shouldn't access the DOM.  You should use the API to inspect the options of an option set, like this:

```js
function testThis() {
    var makeYear = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_makeyear");
    if (!makeYear) { return; }
    console.log(makeYear.getOptions().length + " options currently available");
}
```

Comment: This solution gave me the following error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'getOptions'"

Comment: @CarlosFarmer Whoops, Xrm.Page.getControl should have been Xrm.Page.getAttribute. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to access to generated DOM (for example via onchange event) then optiongroup is available as 
`if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.tagName =='optgroup')
var og = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;`